# ReactJS - Maintaining a numeric value with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm fairly new to React.

I have a few filters in my app, distance & rating.

I want to know to show the count of filters applied to the user.

I created the component level state using

```
const [rating, setRating] = useState([])
const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0)
const [filters, setFitlers] = useState([])
```

An async API call takes place on pageLoad.

I tried using useEffect() by adding dependencies of filters, distance & rating:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // distance filter is mandatory
  if (!filters.includes('distance')) {
    setFilters([...filters, 'distance'])
  }
  if (rating.length > 0) {
    if (!filters.includes('rating')) {
      setFilters([...filters, 'distance'])
    }
  } else {
    setFilters(filters.filter((f) => f !== 'rating'))
  }
}, [filters, distance, rating])
```

But as soon as no rating is selected, I get a React warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.

How do I safely maintain my filter count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are:

- Adding `distance` twice (`[...filters, 'distance']`).
- Might have closure on state's `filters`.
- You have an infinite loop on `filters.includes("rating") === true`, your logic always chooses this path and update state.

Try something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!filters.includes("distance")) {
    setFilters((filters) => [...filters, "distance"]);
  }
  if (rating.length > 0) {
    if (!filters.includes("rating")) {
      setFilters((filters) => [...filters, "rating"]);
    }
  } else {
    setFilters((filters) => {
      const filtered = filters.filter((f) => f !== "rating");
      return filtered.length === filters.length ? filters : filtered;
    });
  }
}, [filters, distance, rating]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the error Maximum update depth exceeded because adding "filters" dependency on useEffect will cause an infinite rendering. useEffect will run whenever "filters" state change and inside your useEffect you performed setFilters() and this cause useEffect runs again and again.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Maximum update depth exceeded` you get is cause by infinite loop / infinite re-renders.

Since you added `filters` in the dependencies of the `UseEffect` and you set the filters value with `setFilters` in it, the `useEffect` will execute an infinite number of times.

I don't really understand why you only get this error while no rating is selected though..

Comment: Answer by Dennis Vash solved my problem. The problem was closure!